# C++ proc_open analogue

Tags: php, c++, cross-platform, popen, stdio

There's a handy function in PHP called [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php). It could be used to call an executable, opening its `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` as pipes.

Is there a good cross-platform version of this function in C++? The only googlable thing is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tutorial for Windows (though code from it just hangs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably get 'somewhere' with

- `popen` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)
- [pstreams library](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/) (POSIX process control) - I have no prior experience with this, but it looks solid and was written by Jonathan Wakely
- Boost Process (http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/, not in boost yet)

  - See also [How to bind program termination with end-of-stream in Boost.Process 0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329065/how-to-bind-program-termination-with-end-of-stream-in-boost-process-0-5/12376196#12376196)
  - and [output with boost process library in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130387/output-with-boost-process-library-in-c)

- Poco::Process `launch` (http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Process.html#13423)

  ```
  static ProcessHandle launch(
     const std::string & command,
      const Args & args,
      Pipe * inPipe,
      Pipe * outPipe,
      Pipe * errPipe
  );
  ```

Comment: Boost Process seems to be not in Boost yet since 2006.

Comment: I'm aware of that, which is why I mentioned it. The naming is a bit confusing that way

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

As I can see, Boost.Process is no longer in the active development, and the examples are not compiling with the current (1.54) and not so current (1.4x - I forgot to write down the exact version before I upgraded boost) versions of boost, so I need to retract my recommendation.

**Original post**

There is [Boost.Process](http://www.netbsd.org/%7Ejmmv/process/index.html) library which you could use. You can find good example [here](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.read_from_child). Also, check [this chapter](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/design.html#process.design.steps) from [here](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/), as well as [this](http://www.highscore.de/cpp/process/).

```
// 
// Boost.Process 
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
// 
// Copyright (c) 2006, 2007 Julio M. Merino Vidal 
// Copyright (c) 2008 Boris Schaeling 
// 
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying 
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt) 
// 

#include <boost/process.hpp> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 

namespace bp = ::boost::process; 

bp::child start_child() 
{ 
    std::string exec = "bjam"; 

    std::vector<std::string> args; 
    args.push_back("--version"); 

    bp::context ctx; 
    ctx.stdout_behavior = bp::capture_stream(); 

    return bp::launch(exec, args, ctx); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    bp::child c = start_child(); 

    bp::pistream &is = c.get_stdout(); 
    std::string line; 
    while (std::getline(is, line)) 
        std::cout << line << std::endl; 
}
```